# Why does Calculating keyboard size sometimes produces a zero height

Tags: swift, uikeyboard

```
@objc private func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        if let info = aNotification.userInfo as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let keyboardFrame = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
                let kbSize = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.size
                containerViewBottomConstraint?.constant = -kbSize.height
                weak var weakSelf = self
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
                    weakSelf?.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried both the UIKeyboardDidShow and UIKeyboardDidShow notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(aNotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(aNotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
```

It only happens rarely and when qa is testing. I can see it calculates the keyboard as zero. Also when I have a hardware keyboard connected and I remove it then I can see in the code that the keyboard height is zero.

Is this a bug with apple's framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hardware Keyboard:

- The notification indicates only the height of the keyboard shown on screen.
- When a hardware keyboard is connected to the device, the keyboard need not be shown on the screen and hence the keyboard the keyboard height would be zero

## Keyboard Height:

I would use `UIKeyboardDidShow` notification and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to get the keyboard frame (and subsequently the height)

```
@objc private func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let endFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else {
            return
    }

    let keyboardHeight = endFrame.height
    
    print("keyboardHeight = \(keyboardHeight)")
}
```

Comment: This seams to work. Do you what is the difference between the ending frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates and the beginning frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates?

Comment: When the keyboard appears on the screen it is usually an animation that starts with start frame rect and ends with the end frame text